# Diophantine equations with egyptian fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am looking for information about the following diophantine equation:
$ \frac{1}{x_1} +\frac{1}{x_2} + \dots \frac{1}{x_k} = \frac{1}{n} \textrm{(k,n fixed)} $

Would it help if n has a special form (square, power of a prime number)?

I searched Google for egyptian fractions, didn't find anything really useful.

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700130/parametric-solution-of-the-diophantine-equation-frac3n-sum-frac1a/1700195#1700195

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice survey article, [Paul Erdös and Egyptian Fractions](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/13_03_Egyptian.pdf) by R.L. Graham, also referring to the well-known Erdős–Straus conjecture.